# Updating A Dynamically Created NSMenu with NSMenuItems

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I have a NSMenu with 3 static NSMenuItems that I want to keep, and a bunch after that are dynamically generated and should be removed and reloaded each time the user clicks the menu icon.

I'm trying to create a list of processes that pop out, but each time I open the popout, the NSMenuItems don't clear. They just add on in some funky way. Logging the for loop shows that the loop isn't completing. Any ideas why?

```
-(void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu *)menu{

    //Keep Top 3 Menu Items
    if(dropDown.numberOfItems > 3){
        NSLog(@"-----------Removing Items");
        NSLog(@"%d",itemCount);
        for(int i = 2; i <= dropDown.numberOfItems; i++){
            NSLog(@"%d",i);
            [dropDown removeItemAtIndex:i];

        }
    }

    NSArray *appArray = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];


    for (NSRunningApplication *r in appArray){
        //NSLog(r.localizedName);
        //NSLog(@"------------");
        NSMenuItem *i = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:r.localizedName 
                                               action:@selector(fooClicked:) keyEquivalent:@""];
        [i setTarget:self];
        [dropDown addItem:i];

        [i release];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is with removal code. Consider this:

```
for(int i = 3; i <= dropDown.numberOfItems; i++){
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    [dropDown removeItemAtIndex:i];
}
```

It should be `i--` at the end. Also - if array has 3 items, the index of last item is 2, hence the declaration of the loop should be following:

```
for(int i = 2; i >= 0; i--){
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    [dropDown removeItemAtIndex:i];
}
```

**Update according to comment**

Removing the items from your menu should be performed backwards or forward, but removing same item index right next after the 2nd item (i.e. removing always 3rd item):

```
for(int i = 2; i <= dropDown.numberOfItems; i++){
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    [dropDown removeItemAtIndex:2];
}
```

or

```
for(int i = dropDown.numberOfItems; i >= 2; i--){
    NSLog(@"%d",i);
    [dropDown removeItemAtIndex:i];
}
```

This is needed because each time you remove `i`th item, the array of items shortens and sometimes you hit the object that is beyond array bounds. Consider this scenario:

1. create array of 3 items
2. iterate from 0 to 2 removing the `i`th item

   1. i = 0, check (i < 3 items) remove the first item, the array of items shortens to 2 (0, 1)
   2. i = 1, check (i < 2 items) remove the first item, the array of items shortens to 1 (0), but only second item is removed so the 0th item is left from previous iteration (which is 1st item from the original set).

This would explain the "funky way".

Comment: Sorry, but I think I need to rephrase my question, it does start at 2, but those are the two menuitems I want to preserve. It's everything after I want to get rid of.

Comment: I've tried both versions and unfortunately the first version gets stuck where my original code did (loop doesn't complete and appends more processes into the list) and the second version doesn't remove any NSMenuItems at all and just appends the process list to the end. Could it be that menuNeedsUpdate is the wrong place to be removing the menu items?

Comment: No. According to documentation `menuNeedsUpdate` is the exact place for menu items' manipulation. Also - I found an error in the second version - there should be `i>=2`, not `i<=2`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That seemed to do it! Thanks for explaining it and putting up with my questions. I'm still a newbie. :) Though I now have an exception to deal with, should I just catch it?  I'm still a bit rough with objective-C, is this an 'array out of bounds' type situation? Reading it it seems to be, but counting backwards I shouldn't go out of bounds correct? `Invalid parameter not satisfying: (index >= 0) && (index < [_itemArray count])`

Comment: I think you should post a second question with updated code, since this is becoming a discussion.